# Software to sort large number of RECOVERED FILES into folders one by one

Tags: windows, file-management

I am looking for software - to sort files one by one

on WINDOWS

my hard was formatted by accident

so when i did recovery - all i got is image001 , image002 ... and so on

it is very hard to open the image, see the content - close it - rename it - move it to the related folder

i need something to do this one by one 
for example i set the folders that files will go into

then it view for me 1st image 
i choose the folder it will go into 
and if i want to rename it

using shortcuts on keyboard 
then the 2nd one ..... and so on ..

so doing a large number in less time

unfortunate the images is not restored with the date modified ..... any thing with helpful info to help me with the problem

what do you recommend ?  Thanks in Advance :D

Comment: If you took any of these with digital camera, they would have EXIF metadata, and you could install the exiftool and do this:  exiftool "-DateTimeOriginal>FileModifyDate"  c:\folder\\*.jpg  Then at least the dates would be restored.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable thumbnails, to save time opening the file.  For Windows 10:

- Open File Explorer.
- Click on the View tab.
- Click Options to open Folder Options.
- Click on the View tab.
- Make sure to clear the check mark for the Always show icons, never thumbnails option.
- Click Apply.
- Click OK to complete the task.

You can show "Date Taken" as one of the Windows folder columns:

- Click on the View tab.
- Select "Details"
- Right-click on the column heading of the folder (Name, Date, etc)
- Select "Date taken", or "More..." and "Date taken"

Then you can use F2 for renaming, and any other keyboard shortcuts to save time.